# como hacer la media oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

necesito hacer la media de los retrasos de una base de datos de vuelos.

Necesito añadirla a la siguiente query:

```
SELECT V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino AS Id_Aeropuerto, C.Nombre AS Ciudad_Destino, A.nombre AS Aeropuerto,
(SELECT SUM((TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Salida,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')) + 
        (TO_NUMBER(V.Retraso_Llegada,'99999999D99','nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')))
        FROM Vuelo V
        WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=Id_Aeropuerto) Retraso_Total
FROM Ciudad C, Aeropuerto A, Vuelo V
WHERE V.Id_Aeropuerto_Destino=A.Id_Aeropuerto AND A.Ciudad = C.Id_Ciudad;
```

para que la query completa sacase

```
Id_aeropuerto, 
nombre_ciudad, 
nombre_aeropuerto, 
media_retraso de ese aeropuerto y 
total_retraso de ese aeropuerto.
```

se que se hace con `AVG`, pero desconozco el como.

gracias!

Answer (score 2):

No veo la necesidad de utilizar una sub-consulta, además con tu diseño original saldrán muchas filas repetidas (una por cada vuelo) conteniendo la misma información del aeropuerto.

He re-escrito tu query para devolver una sola fila por aeropuerto, que creo que es lo que buscas

```
select   a.id_Aeropuerto
       , c.Nombre Ciudad
       , a.Nombre Aeropuerto
       , avg(  to_number(v.Retraso_Salida, '99999999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
             + to_number(v.Retrado_Llegada, '99999999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
            ) Retraso_Promedio
       , sum(  to_number(v.Retraso_Salida, '99999999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
             + to_number(v.Retrado_Llegada, '99999999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,''')
            ) Retraso_Total
  from Ciudad c
       inner join Aeropuerto a on c.id_ciudad = a.Ciudad
       inner join Vuelo v on v.id_Aeropuerto_Destino = a.id_Aeropuerto
 group by a.id_Aeropuerto
        , c.Nombre
        , a.Nombre
```

Esto lo hago valiendome de la clausula `group by` y de las funciones de agregación `sum` y `avg`, que me devolverán la suma y el promedio del tiempo de retraso, respectivamente.